# How to open menu with menuInflator when an on screen button is pressed?

Tags: android, button, menu

I have a button in my screen and i want to open up the menuInflator when the button is pressed i tried the following code but it does not work

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
          case R.id.btnmenu1:
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MenuInflater inflatemenu = getMenuInflater();
            inflatemenu.inflate(R.menu.bmenu, menu);
            break;
 }
```

How do i make it work???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Call `openOptionsMenu();` method when click on button

or else set `android:onClick="myOnClickMethod"` on your `Button` in xml and then have:

```
public myOnClickMethod(View v) {
    openOptionsMenu();
}
```

in your activity.